# Variable Caption spacing for `tikzpicture` and `tabular`

Tags: spacing, captions

The `\abovecaptionskip` option gives different results with `tikzpicture` and `tabular`.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{report}        
\usepackage{tikz}    
%    
\begin{document}    
  \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}    
  \begin{figure}    
    \centering    
    \begin{tikzpicture}    
      \node[rectangle] {Some Figure};    
      \draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{A Caption}  
%   
    \vspace{1cm}
%   
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
      \hline
      Nonlinear & 3.720894e-0\\ \hline
    \end{tabular} 
    \caption{B Caption}
  \end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

On an unrelated note, how do I include `figure` environment in `standalone` `documentclass`?

Comment: It's the tikzpicture orientation. Add `[baseline]` option to the Tikz picture and it should give similar results. And use `[preview]` option ; `\documentclass[preview]{standalone}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you put the environment `tikzpicture` inside a box, it has height `15.84369pt` and depth `0pt`, because the reference point is at the bottom border. Then TeX applies the usual interline algorithm, the next base line has distance `\baselineskip`.

In case of `tabular`, the default reference point is centered regarding the mathematical axis (`\vcenter` is used for vertical centering). The result: the height is `8.9pt` and the depth is `3.9pt`. If the usual algorithm for `\baselineskip` gives a inter line space smaller than `\lineskiplimit`, then TeX uses `\lineskip` instead (default is `1pt`).

If you want similar spacing then the reference point of the `tabular` can be moved
downwards with the optional placement option `b`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[rectangle] {Some Figure};
      \draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{A Caption}

    \vspace{1cm}

    \begin{tabular}[b]{|l|l|}
      \hline
      Nonlinear & 3.720894e-0\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{B Caption}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Or in the other direction, the reference point of `tikzpicture` can be changed, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
      \node[rectangle] {Some Figure};
      \draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{A Caption}

    \vspace{1cm}

    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}   
      \hline
      Nonlinear & 3.720894e-0\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{B Caption}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The extreme, without any space can be achieved by `\nointerlineskip`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
      \node[rectangle] {Some Figure};
      \draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \nointerlineskip
    \caption{A Caption}

    \vspace{1cm}

    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
      \hline
      Nonlinear & 3.720894e-0\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \nointerlineskip
    \caption{B Caption}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: This is wonderful. I am interested in getting a uniform spacing for all captions. Should I use the first or the second choice. I can always set `abovecaptionskip` accordingly. I ask this, as I am not aware of the complete consequences of adding `baseline` to all my `tikzpictures`.